# Debug error: &"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n"

Tags: debugging, gdb, qt-creator, ubuntu-14.04

I've recently updated my system to Ubuntu 14.04 LTE. I've also updated the version of my QtCreator to 3.3.

When I run in Release mode, no problem. However, when I tried to debug, something strange happens: The system throws a Segmentation Fault, and the application give me this message:

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n"
```

I saw other comments that propose to downgrade the GDB version from 7.8 to 7.7 and other saying the opposite thing. I tried both but nothing works.
I saw some posts saying that it's a bug, but I'm not being able to find any solution in these messages.

Have anyone some suggestions?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

I tried to use gdb via command line, and it works a little bit different: The segmentation fault remains, but the error is different:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff1da2a70 in boost::math::lanczos::lanczos_initializer<boost::math::lanczos::lanczos17m64, long double>::init::init() ()
   from /usr/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so.1.7
```

I removed the flag -std=c++0x from my makefile in order to not use c++11. Then, using command line gdb, the debugging works. However, using QtCreator it still not working.

Any idea? Thaaanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this message  every time I debug, but the debugging works fine. I'm sure I found a comment on the QT forums that says just ignore it.

Have you tried debugging a trivial "hello world" program?

Comment: Yes, it's true. Certainly, now I can debug, with the same warning but the program finishes. I tried with other debugging interfaces and it works. I change the QtCreator version different times and, now, it works. I don't know what was happening. It's so strange. Thanks for your comment!